# How can i order by column with data "01","02","03","1","2","3" and so on in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I am having SQL table with data as shown below

```
01  Buy-1
010 Buy-10
011 Buy-11
02  Buy-2
1   Direct-1
10  Direct-10
11  Direct-11
2   Direct-2
```

I want to order by the data like this

```
01  Buy-1
02  Buy-2
010 Buy-10
011 Buy-11    
1   Direct-1
2   Direct-2
10  Direct-10
11  Direct-11
```

Comment: Ack....those leading zeros are painful.

Comment: Store numbers as numbers, not as text.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The OP posted sample data, desired output and clearly explained what they are trying to accomplish.

Comment: As pointed out by @MatBailie, the problem is your data type. Strings and numbers have *very* different sorting behaviour. It seems you want a mix of both, which is never going to be fun.

Comment: @MatBailie They are imported from another database and i have no control over it.

Comment: Perhaps sort values with a leading zero first, and then sort as an `int`?

Comment: _i have no control over it_ Yes you do - you can transform it during import and store those values separately so you have the "actual" values (mostly decorative) and the useful versions of that same information that will make your queries much easier and much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a little extra handling of the strings to get the right sorting criteria.

Assuming your data is consistent with your sample data with a hyphen followed by digits you can order by the data to the left of the hyphen and then by casting the first column as an int

```
select id, data
from t
order by Left(data, nullif(CharIndex('-',data),0)-1),
  Try_Cast(id as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an intriguing problem and I had to come back and find a solution to this issue as it has been seen many times over the years. When you don't have the leading zeros it is a fairly easy solution but this is different.

This works for your sample data and even some edge cases that I tried. The ordering first effectively counts the number of number of leading zeros and moves that with the most leading zeros to the top. Then it orders by converting the value to an int. This allows you to have more than 1 leading zero and it will still sort correctly. Additionally it will work even if you have character data in the first column.

```
declare @Something table
(
    SomeValue varchar(10)
    , SomeOtherValue varchar(30)
)

insert @Something
select '01' , 'Buy-1' union all
select '010', 'Buy-10' union all
select '011', 'Buy-11' union all
select '02', 'Buy-2' union all
select '1', 'Direct-1' union all
select '10', 'Direct-10' union all
select '11', 'Direct-11' union all
select '2', 'Direct-2'

select *
from @Something s
order by len(SomeValue) - len(convert(varchar(10), try_convert(int, SomeValue))) desc
    , try_convert(int, SomeValue)
```

Comment: I would expect that there is a need to sort by the first 'word' in SomeOtherValue, then by the numeric value (numerically).

Comment: @MatBailie actually in this case you do. The first order by will sort the leading zeros to the top of the list. Without that the leading zeros would be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Id: 01
_Value: Buy-1

```
SELECT Id, _Value from tblName order by left(_Value, CHARINDEX('-', _Value)), cast(SUBSTRING(_Value, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', _Value),len(_Value)) as int)
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It would return the values ordered as a string. So you would get 1, 10, 11, 2

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I added cast(val, as int). You can try...

Answer (score 0):

I would first order by your code having a leading zero, and secondly by the code value itself.

```
select code, description
from MyTable
order by case when left(code,1) = '0' then 0 else 1 end,
         convert(int, code)
```